# Display Bug on Careers Permissions Declaration

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, opera

It seems that the Stack Overflow Careers account signup requires you to pass a small test of inference before it deems you worthy.

On the [permissions dialog](https://stackexchange.com:443/oauth?client_id=375&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2fgateway%2fstack), I see two hollow orange lozenges below the declaration:

[image: The buttons on the permissions dialog are invisible.]

When I hover the cursor over the left lozenge, it fills itself in with 'Approve':

[image: The Approve button appears when you hover over it.]

When I hover the cursor over the right lozenge, it fills itself in with 'Reject':

[image: The Reject button appears when you hover over it.]

Is this a real test, or just a mystery-meat-navigation bug?

My browser is Opera 12.02.

**Spoiler Alert**: It was a challenge, but I worked out that if I click inside the left lozenge, my reward is an account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had some missing styles for Opera, they've been fixed in the latest deploy.